# Drawing Shapes on a PDF with C# WinForm

Tags: c#, pdf, shapes

I have been searching for help with this for a long time. If it's been answered here already, I cannot find it. I'm using C# on a Windows Form.

I'm trying to create a simple program that allows me to open a PDF, flatten any layers within it, and then, for each click of the mouse, draw a circle.

Centered within each circle I need to have a number, beginning with "1", and chronologically increasing to infinity (could be 1, could be 15000).

Finally, I need to be able to save, and print the final result.

There are other things I need to add, but if someone can get me started with this, I should be able to figure out the rest on my own.

I've been able to import the .pdf. However, any tut I've found for creating a transparent layer on which to draw, never allows me to see the pdf behind. Do I even need this transparent layer, or can I draw directly on the pdf? My second biggest issue figuring out is how to create the circle, with the chronologically increasing number anywhere I choose to click my mouse.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Please see the image below for what it should look like.

[image: sample]

Comment: Which (if any) pdf lib are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Atalasoft's DotImage/DotPdf/DotAnnotate packages (disclaimer: I used to work on these products up until 3 years ago). There are a number of ways to do this. If you don't care the markup being an annotation, you can make an annotation with a custom appearance and add each one to the document.
If you care that the numbers get added to the document, you can use DotPdf directly to append content to the content stream of any page.

How to do this on your own. Good luck (seriously - this is not an easy problem to solve).
Here's what you need to be able to do first (at a minimum) for putting new content into an existing page:

First, let's talk about the PDF rendering model:
PDF uses a little non-Turing complete RPN language to place content on the page. A given page has one or more streams of code which gets executed in order to render a page. If you want add content on top, you need to render it last (there are other more complicated ways to do this, but this is good enough). That means you either append to the existing content stream (wouldn't recommend), or you take advantage of the fact that a PDF page can have any number of content streams on it. You make a new stream and add in the code to render the content that you want.
I'll warn you ahead of time that rendering text is non-trivial, especially if you have to embed fonts or use unicode encoding. I'll also warn you that there is no "circle" primitive in PDF. You have to approximate it with Bezier curves.
I'm studious in my laziness, so I created abstractions to make it easier to correctly create content streams. For example, I make a class called a drawing surface and I could tell it "set the drawing style to this" "place a 'shape' here" "draw text here" and so on. When it was told to render, it would generate the PDF rendering program that matched. On top of this, I had another abstraction that consisted of a drawing list of higher level objects and the drawing list, when rendered would write to the drawing surface which would in turn write PDF.

1. Append changes (generations) to a PDF
2. Create Content streams
3. Append a replacement page object for an existing page with the Contents changed from a Stream to an array (or if it's an array already, append to it) and with new resources added to the Resource dictionary

Here's what you need to be able to do first (at a minimum) for putting annotations on an existing page:

1. Append changes (generations) to a PDF
2. Append a replacement page object for an existing page with the Annots added with new annotations (or modified by inserting/appending new annotations)
3. Create appearance streams
4. Create annotations with using the custom appearance streams

As far as how to do the UI, that's oddly straight forward as long as you have a PDF renderer. Render a page into an image and make a control that gives you a mouse click onto the page. Then build a transformation matrix that goes from image coordinates to PDF page coordinates and push the mouse coordinates through that matrix. The result will be the origin of your mark up on the page (be aware that some pages are rotated and you will need to adjust your transformation matrix to match).

Now, to be clear, when I wrote this library for Atalasoft, I already had several years of PDF experience (I worked on Acrobat v 1 - 4). While I wasn't working on the library full time, it was written over the span of 10 years. The code to append to an existing PDF took several months of time to get right. Eventually, I shed that code because of complications in appending anything but simple changes (like annotations) and wrote code that could rewrite an entire PDF with updates to existing content (page reordering, annotations, bookmarks, new content on a page, edited images, etc), while simultaneously shedding anything that is no longer needed. This is akin to adding in and clipping out sections of a directed graph with cycles and being able to ensure that you have a correct graph on the other end.
The hard part wasn't working within the specification - that's fairly straightforward for me. The problem was dealing with cockamamie PDF generated by other tools that had all kinds of bizarro spec violations and handling that correctly.

Now, I'm not saying don't do this. I'm all for people learning new things and learning about PDF. There's a lot there to learn and a lot of interesting ideas, but you need to be aware that simple sounding problems in PDF space aren't trivial unless you have a great deal of infrastructure in place. For example, "how many pages are in a PDF?" requires a PDF scanner and code to execute or parse PDF content so you can read in the cross reference table (which may be a compressed cross reference stream), the document dictionary (which may include encryption), and finally the page tree: all which can be easily derailed by non-compliant PDF.

If you're trying to balance time and cost, remember that your time is far from free and maybe a library to do the heavy lifting is not a bad thing. iTextPdf is open source and can do all of the things you need to do, but it will cost you in time to learn the library, but that's a huge savings over having to write PDF tools on your own. Atalasoft's code is not free, but was written to have a much shallower learning curve than most libraries.

Comment: Looks like a commercial product, yes?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is why I'm trying to figure this out on my own. There are many products that can do what I need to do, however there are none (that I have found) that do ONLY what I need it to do.

All of the other bells and whistles that come with it are pointless, and costly overhead that I do not need.

Comment: @Tod, this sounds as if you already got much of it working with code of your own? But not knowing anything about it, how could we tell you how to expand it??

Comment: No, I don't have anything working. Maybe I wasn't very clear. I have tried many things with no success.

Comment: Thanks plinth. This may be a dumb question, but if I can already open a pdf, why can I not add a transparent layer over it, draw circles on that layer with the graphics class, and print that out? I do not need to manipulate the original pdf in any way.

It would be the same as opening a jpg, drawing to it, and printing that out.

Are you able to direct me to where I can create a circle shape anywhere I click the mouse?

Comment: That's a way different question. Way different. And here's why it's not the same as opening a jpg: PDF has no resolution - it's primarily an outline based format. When you display a PDF page, you're showing a fixed view of the contents of the page. If you treat it as a fixed image, alter the image and save it as a PDF, you get an image-only PDF and all scalability that might have been present gets lost.

Comment: If you want to do that, make a windows control that uses as it's model an image and a list of your annotations. In the Paint method, paint the image and all the annotations on top of it. In the Click method, grab the mouse coordinates, create a new annotation at that location, add it to the model, then invalidate the bounds of the annotation so it redraws. When you save, render the image and the annotations to an offscreen bitmap and write it in your favorite format.